# how to write mpeg4 file in vc++ directshow

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

hai..

Am writing application for capture video from camera in vc++ using directshow and write that
file in WMV format.and how to write MPEG4 file format.can i install any sdk for mpeg4.can you provide details about mpeg file writing in vc++

kindly help me
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear if you want to change the video format or just the container format. If you just want to write the existing camera output into a different container file, then you need a multiplexor filter. There's an MP4 multiplexor filter available in source form at www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4. If you connect your camera's output to this filter and then the file writer, you should be ok.

If, on the other hand, you need to encode the camera output to mpeg-4 video as well, then I think you will need to licence a third-party encoder filter.

G